# How to convert json string datatype column to map datatype column in hive?

Tags: json, hive, hiveql

[image]

**I need to get all the unique key values from all the rows**. **Each row has different keys and values** Please find the above image of the column.

eg: one row looks like

```
{"START_TIME":1549002807568,"PARSING.QUERY_FORMED":1549002807586,"CUBES_WITH_PERMISSIONS":1549002807568,"PARSING.CUBE_MATCH_SELECTED":1549002807586,"POTENTIAL_COMPLETIONS_ADDED":1549002807587,"QUERY_PARSED":1549002807586,"SUGGESTIONS_FORMED":1549002807606,"PARSING.SEQUENCES_GENERATED":1549002807568,"PARSING.NGRAM_MATCHES_CACHED":1549002807585}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested this with two rows of data, all key_value pairs are identical except in second JSON there is one additional `NEW_KEY` and `PARSING.NGRAM_MATCHES_CACHED` values are different.

```
with data as
(
select stack(2, --data example
'{"START_TIME":1549002807568,"PARSING.QUERY_FORMED":1549002807586,"CUBES_WITH_PERMISSIONS":1549002807568,"PARSING.CUBE_MATCH_SELECTED":1549002807586,"POTENTIAL_COMPLETIONS_ADDED":1549002807587,"QUERY_PARSED":1549002807586,"SUGGESTIONS_FORMED":1549002807606,"PARSING.SEQUENCES_GENERATED":1549002807568,"PARSING.NGRAM_MATCHES_CACHED":1549002807585}',
'{"NEW_KEY":12345,"START_TIME":1549002807568,"PARSING.QUERY_FORMED":1549002807586,"CUBES_WITH_PERMISSIONS":1549002807568,"PARSING.CUBE_MATCH_SELECTED":1549002807586,"POTENTIAL_COMPLETIONS_ADDED":1549002807587,"QUERY_PARSED":1549002807586,"SUGGESTIONS_FORMED":1549002807606,"PARSING.SEQUENCES_GENERATED":1549002807568,"PARSING.NGRAM_MATCHES_CACHED":154900280758}'
) as str
)

select str_to_map(concat_ws(',',collect_set(key_value)),',',':') --collect set, concatenate and convert to map
from
(
select explode(split(regexp_replace (str,'[{}"]',''),',')) key_value from data --remove JSON delimiters, split and explode pairs
)s;
```

Result:

```
OK
{"START_TIME":"1549002807568","PARSING.QUERY_FORMED":"1549002807586","CUBES_WITH_PERMISSIONS":"1549002807568","PARSING.CUBE_MATCH_SELECTED":"1549002807586","POTENTIAL_COMPLETIONS_ADDED":"1549002807587","QUERY_PARSED":"1549002807586","SUGGESTIONS_FORMED":"1549002807606","PARSING.SEQUENCES_GENERATED":"1549002807568","PARSING.NGRAM_MATCHES_CACHED":"154900280758","NEW_KEY":"12345"}
Time taken: 158.414 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Of course, `"PARSING.NGRAM_MATCHES_CACHED"` exists only one time in the result, because map does not allow the same key twice. All key_values are unique.
Read comments in the code please.