# How to flatten a hive column which contains JSON data

Tags: hadoop, hive

There is a hive table with only one column and which is supposed to contain JSON in each record. Note that in each record, the JSON structure might vary. I want to flatten the JSON and create a table with all JSON keys. Is it possible? If yes, could you suggest how to do? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [**JSONSerDe**](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde) and define the superset of columns or better define only those columns you need. Only columns defined in the table DDL will be parsed, NULLs will be loaded if such keys are absent in JSON row. Anyway you need to know possible keys to create a table with columns from JSON parsed.

Alternatively you can convert JSON to map if you want to extract both key and value existing in JSON and JSON is simple flat one, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54766529/2700344

Answer (score 0):

You can try something as below:

Say you have a column with JSON data something like this in a table called *json_test*

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| col1                                                      |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| {"variable1":123,"variable2":456,"variable3":789}         |                                          
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| {"variable1":222,"variable2":333,"variable3":444}         |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

And if you want to parse this you can run the below hive statement to parse it. Every row can have different JSON format. If the query finds the attribute, it will return the value else it will return NULL

```
select get_json_object(col1,'$.variable1') as variable1,
get_json_object(col1,'$.variable2') as variable2,
get_json_object(col1,'$.variable3') as variable3 
from json_test
```

Output:

```
|variable1 |variable2 |variable3 |
|----------|----------|----------|
|123       |456       |789       |
|222       |333       |444       |
```